# What do these residual patterns tell me?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

I am doing a regression analysis with multiple variables and comparing it to a one-variable null hypothesis. The goal is to see which model provides a better explanation. The topic is information diffusion, hence the names DIFfusion, INDustry, etc. Also I must say that DIF is many times zero (has a long tail) and all variables go between 0 and 1. Anyways, the hypothesis can be translated unto:

H_0: DIF ~ REL

H_1: DIF ~ REL+COM*REL+IND*REL

H_2: DIF ~ REL+COM*REL+IND*REL+SIZE1+SIZE2

REL multiplies the other two variables as theoretically they are related and together they 'should' give a better prediction of DIF.

Now, the tricky things for me are two.

First, (and most importantly), although R values are over 0.6 -good enough for this topic- when I see the residuals they tend to follow a pattern that is similar for all three hypotheses. I really don't know why or how to address it.

[image: Residuals]

[image: QQplot]

[image: histogram]

Second, I have the intuition that the dependent variable (DIF) behaves like an iceberg and sea-level. Meaning that the lower the sea level (represented by SIZE1-2), I could see more of the shape of the iceberg, where the shape of the iceberg is given by the other variables. Have you encountered situations like this? How would you model/test it?

Any advice?

Using R by the way.

Comment: R-square is not the right statistic to determine the best model for prediction. If you have enough data, you should set aside a portion to use for testing prediction, and only fit the model on the rest. Regarding you second question, it's hard to tell without knowing more about the underlying problem. This looks like you have fatter tails and some serious heteroskedasticity. Try transforming the data (using `log`, for instance).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I will try your first advice. On the other note, the problem is that the value of DIF is only >0 when the dependent variables -specially SIZE- are 'large enough', otherwise is 0. Any ideas on how to model that. I tried transforming log and sqrt but it kept having the same shape, only improved R-square.

Comment: For models when you only observe the effect when it is about a certain threshold you could use Heckman's selection model. It was devised in labor economics where the productivity of an individual (the salary the job market would offer them) can only be observed if they have a paying job. That would happen only if the wage is higher than what the individual considers a sufficient amount for him/her to take a job (and give up free time).